# execfile with automatic relative path

Tags: python, python-2.7, ironpython, execfile

I need to be able to call python scripts via execfile() from outside the working directory without specifying the relative file path each time through the interpreter.

instead of:

```
execfile("..\\UserScripts\\HelloWorld.py")
```

I need to call:

```
execfile("HelloWorld.py")
```

is there a sys.path I can add this to that makes this work? The directories are fixed, as are the locations of the working directory and the file. The expectation is that a user can drop a file into the UserScripts directory and expect to be able to call it through the interpreter without the relative file path.

Comment: Can you change the current working directory?

Comment: No, the current working directory is fixed; as is the location of HelloWorld.py they are not the same directory, but their relative path is always the same.

Answer (score 1):

The script below assumes that HelloWorld.py is in the same directory as your executable.

```
import os.path
import sys

execfile(os.path.join( os.path.dirname(sys.argv[0]), 'HelloWorld.py'))
```

However, if you have a subdir where you keep snippets (let's call it '../UserSnippets') you can specify the path relative to the script that contains the execfile:

```
execfile(os.path.join( os.path.dirname(sys.argv[0]), '..','UserSnippets','HelloWorld.py'))
```

Using os.path.join keeps the code portable ( I hope, I only tested on my Mac ).

Answer (score 0):

I would strongly recommend using a different name (say `execscript`), which you can add to the scope you execute the user scripts in:

```
scope.SetVariable("execscript", (CodeContext context, string filename) => {
    Builtins.execfile(context, Patch.Combine("../../Scripts", filename));
});
```

That will make it appear as a builtin without mucking with the builtins dictionary.

If it has to be `execfile`, your best bet is going to be to replace the `execfile` builtin with one that patches up the directory and then calls into the old `execfile`. Here's some completely untested, uncompiled code that should point you in the right direction:

```
var engine = Python.CreateEngine();
var builtins = engine.GetBuiltinModule();
builtins.SetVariable("execfile", (CodeContext context, string filename) => {
    Builtins.execfile(context, Patch.Combine("../../Scripts", filename));
});
```